# Why are two separate MySQL statements duplicating each other?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a require file that I use to display random products. On the home page it gets used twice, once in the main content section and then again in the sidebar.

The problem I'm having is the second require doesn't overwrite the first sql results, it adds to them? The results I'm actually getting for the 2nd set of results are the 1st set plus the 2nd.

Here's the first bit of code I use to select the products:

`SELECT id FROM prods ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10`

Then this uses those to fill out the rows:

`SELECT * , MIN( price ) AS minPrice, MAX( price ) AS maxPrice, COUNT( id ) AS numMerchants FROM prods WHERE id IN ('.$sqlIn.') GROUP BY name ORDER BY RAND()`

I'm sure I've overlooked something but can't think what it is.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in the way this is embedded into the PHP rather than in the SQL itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you assigning the two queries/results to the same variable? If that is the case the resulting PHP array will append any new results. Try assigning to either a different variable, or using unset($results).

Comment: its assigned to $sql each time as its reusing the require file. The $sql should just be redefined though when used a 2nd time?

Comment: can you add a php excerpt to the question? depending on the dataset/array structure/sequence the variable may be being added to and not overwritten. You may fund that running unset($sql) before you then use the variable for the second statement corrects the issue

Comment: Was just looking at the variables and realised $sqlin doesn't redefine itself. So the SQL is fine but the WHERE IN() statement gets appended to.

Comment: Ergo, do you happen to own a crystal ball? How did you guess that?!? :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `SELECT` should be without the `*`. Also, why are you ordering by `RAND()` in the query as well.

```
SELECT MIN( price ) AS minPrice, MAX( price ) AS maxPrice, COUNT( id ) AS numMerchants FROM prods 
WHERE id IN ('.$sqlIn.') GROUP BY name
```

---

In the first query, you are doing `ORDER BY RAND()` - this is awfully slow - do you absolutely need to do this? Google for other solutions of picking random rows from a table without shooting the server down.

Comment: I inherited the code so am gradually making changes, I'll check out a rand() alternative. The select won't work without the *

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to provide any real help.

What variable are you storing the results in?  Are you running the SQL statement twice and thus loading the variable twice? According to PHP include/require documentation:

( http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php )

> When a file is included, the code it
>   contains inherits the variable scope
>   of the line on which the include
>   occurs. Any variables available at
>   that line in the calling file will be
>   available within the called file, from
>   that point forward. However, all
>   functions and classes defined in the
>   included file have the global scope.

If that is your problem, can you put an IF check around the variable so that you only load it once? i.e.

```
if (isset($myResults))
{
  load
}
// else do nothing because already loaded in the first require
```